# Call function in child component defined in parent component angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two components app and child. in child component I have button on click of which I am calling a function (function name is assigned to a variable which make it dynamic) which is defines in app component. But this is not working. Any help?

**app.ts**

```
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
  <div>
    <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    <child-comp></child-comp>
    <p>{{data}}</p>
  </div>
`,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  data: string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
  dummyFunction(){  // I want to call this function
      data = "function called";
  }
}
```

**Child.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-comp',
  template: `
    <input type="button" value="click me" (click) = [funcName]()>  // Here I am calling the function which is assign to a variable
  `,
})
export class ChildComp {
  funcName: string;
  constructor() {
    funcName = 'dummyFunction';  // assigning function name to variable
  }
}
```

[Attaching Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WsWK8O9iXDHLJHe2lRwX)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do exactly what you are describing, but can achieve the same thing using the `Output` decorator and `EventEmitter` as described in the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent) for parent-child component communication.

Your child component can emit an event, `buttonClicked` below, and the parent component (i.e. app) can bind to that event with the required callback (i.e. `dummyFunction()`)

App component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <child-comp (buttonClicked)="dummyFunction()"></child-comp>
      <p>{{data}}</p>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  data: string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  dummyFunction(){ // I want to call this function
    this.data = "function called";
  }
}
```

And child component

```
import {Component, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'child-comp',
  template: `
    <input type="button" value="click me" (click) = "onClick($event)"> // Here I am calling the function which is assign to a variable
  `,
})
export class ChildComp {

  @Output() buttonClicked = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() {
  }

  onClick($event){
    this.buttonClicked.emit($event);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if call only child method

**Child.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-comp',
  template: `
    <input type="button" value="click me" (click)="this[funcName]()">  // Here I am calling the function which is assign to a variable
  `,
})
export class ChildComp {
  funcName: string;
  constructor() {
    this.funcName = 'dummyFunction';  // assigning function name to variable
  }
  dummyFunction() {
    console.log('do something')
  }
}
```

or

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-comp',
  template: `
    <input type="button" value="click me" (click)="funcName()"> // callhere
  `,
})
export class ChildComp {
  funcName: Fn;
  constructor() {
    this.funcName = this.dummyFunction.bind(this);  // assigning function to variable
  }
  dummyFunction() {
    console.log('do something')
  }
}
```

if you need communicate from parent and child:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-comp',
  template: `
    <input type="button" value="click me" (click)="funcName()"> // callhere
  `,
})
export class ChildComp {
  @Input()
  funcName: Fn;
  constructor() {
  }
}

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
  <div>
    <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    <child-comp [funcName]="dummyFunction"></child-comp>
    <p>{{data}}</p>
  </div>
`,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  data: string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2';
    this.dummyFunction = this.dummyFunction.bind(this);
  }
  dummyFunction(){  // I want to call this function
      data = "function called";
  }
}
```

or using Output

```
import {Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'child-comp',
  template: `
    <input type="button" value="click me" (click)="onClick($event)">
  `,
})
export class ChildComp {

  @Output() eventName = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() {

  }
  onClick(e) {
    // do something here
    this.eventName.emit(e);
  }
}
```

parent:

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
  <div>
    <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    <child-comp (eventName)="dummyFunction()"></child-comp>
    <p>{{data}}</p>
  </div>
`,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  data: string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2';
  }
  dummyFunction(){  // I want to call this function
      data = "function called";
  }
}
```